# response redirect from .ashx file

Tags: .net, ashx

I have ashx file and I want to redirect from ashx to aspx page. Some solution?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
     context.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using context.Response.Redirect(newUrl); results in a page that says:

"Object moved to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048974/response-redirect-from-ashx-file)."

Update: 
This happened because I signed out, in that case the answer is to use FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();