# Redirect from .ashx to .aspx using $.ajax()

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

If I use the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048974/response-redirect-from-ashx-file), I won't get transferred to the new page. But if i inspect the `$.ajax()` call in the console, the actual .aspx page seems to be in the response body. So my guess is that the .ashx gets redirected to the .aspx.

```
void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
     context.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
}
```

How do I redirect the user from the .aspx page that sends the ajax request? Do I need to call a method on that .aspx from my handler.ashx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Response.Redirect` command is nothing more than instructions to the browser to move to some  other page. This commands are first a header instruction to the browser. Also there is a javascript small script that is written on the page in case the header is fail.

Now, when you make the call with Ajax (no matter if its handler or page) the results return to the page but inside the ajax buffer, the redirect headers are "eaten" and not go to the browser itself to runs them. So no redirect can be directly done via ajax call.

What you should do, is to return a signal to your ajax call, and see that signal/flag and make the redirect using javascript call `window.location.replace("redirectPage.aspx")`

For example, something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action.ashx",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)     
    {
        if(data.NeedRedirect)
            window.location.replace("WhereToMove.aspx");
    },
    error: function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        window.location.replace("WhereToMove.aspx");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to refer to the aspx httpcontext from the ashx file so that i can make the transfter in the server code?

Comment: @Johan You do not make any transfer in the server code. The server code is only write and send some html page, that include some headers that make the transfer. You believe that the transfer is made on server because simple the browser did not show you the middle page.

Comment: @Johan If you handler did not return any data on the ajax, to make the redirect work, just call it as any page without ajax. Eg as link, or with javascript you can call it with the window.location.replace()... etc (not ajax and the redirect work)

Comment: The problem is that the call should be made on a click of a `confirm()` dialog. Thats why I'm using ajax. But I guess client side transfer is the way to go. Thanks

Comment: @Johan On the confirm, just call it without ajax, is the same - try it.

Comment: How should I call a serverside method from javascript without ajax?

Comment: @Johan Server side no, a handler as you say yes,

Comment: @Johan call it with javascript as:  `window.location.replace("yourhandler.ashx");`