# python-requests removing username and password parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

I am having an issue with python-requests and doing some searching I have not been able to find a solution. I have a web handler that accepts a few parameters which include the username and password. When requests goes to make the request.

```
self._get_query() returns {'username': 'test', 'password', 'test', 'check', 'True'}
r = requests.get(self._site, params=self._get_query())
r.text = "No username or password provided"
```

Doing some inspection on on run I see that my username and password parameters are being excluded from the *dict*.

```
r.url = r'http://localhost/test.ashx?check=True'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening?

P.S. The site does not use basic authentication or anything where `requests.get(auth=<something>)` would help. The username and password parameter is passed to the *ashx* for a back-end login.

Comment: Is there anything in `r.history`?

Comment: @sigmavirus24 - Yes, I get two response 302 objects back from `r.history` and looking at the `r.history[0].url` it shows the username and password in the query. So I guess my issue is with the webserver? The text returned from the objects states `<Object Moved>` in the html...

Comment: yes, the issue is indeed with the webserver.

Comment: Also you should check `r.headers['Location']` on the header from that 302 response. It should be the url that you're seeing without the user/password parameters.

Comment: Yup looking in `r.headers['Location']` I can see where the web handler is doing a redirect to the login page (though it is not suppose to do that since the credentials are supplied) I can see what exactly is going on. Thank you for the assistance.

**Reference:** [Response Redirect From ASHX File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048974/response-redirect-from-ashx-file)